# Slide up animation not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Clicking a blue background element in my code should smoothly slide this element up. Instead, it disappears in a clumsy, non-animated way.

What's wrong in my code?

[JSFiddle #1](https://jsfiddle.net/goldorak/k4h71y6z/35/)

The problem even persists when simplifying the code by manually assigning the `max-height` value to the element: [JSFiddle #2](https://jsfiddle.net/goldorak/k4h71y6z/38/)

JS:

```
data: {
  showDiv: true,
  maxHeight: ''
},
methods: {
  async handleClick() {
    await this.$nextTick();
    this.maxHeight = `${this.$refs.divRef?.clientHeight}px`;
    console.log(this.maxHeight);
    this.showDiv = false;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<transition name="slide">
  <div v-if="showDiv" @click="handleClick" ref="divRef" class="content" :style="{ 'max-height': maxHeight }">
    content...
  </div>
</transition>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  background: blue;
}

.slide-leave-active {
  animation: slide-up 2s;
}

@keyframes slide-up {
  0% {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  100% {
    max-height: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS will work fine.  <s>In Vue, transitions should be fired using classes and transitions, not CSS animations.</s> **Edit:** I was incorrect, you *can* in fact use CSS animations in Vue transitions with [some caveats](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#css-animations).

```css
.content {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-leave-active {
  max-height: 100vh;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease;
}

.slide-leave-to {
  max-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Works, thanks! But why can't CSS animations be used in Vue transitions? I've never seen such warning before.

Comment: Now that I'm looking at the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#css-based-transitions), it looks like it _is_ possible.  My mistake - I'll correct my answer.  For simple changes like height animations, it's definitely more convenient to simply use the classes, but it does appear you could use animations as well.